# Flatten array in row in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples, flatten, flatmap

I have Spark code in Scala like this:

```
scala> myfile.filter(!_.contains("BatchNumber")).map(line=>line.split("\t")).map(line=>Row(line(0),(for (i <- 30 to 33) yield line(i)),line(1))).take(2)
```

the result of above code is below, which is not what I want

```
res85: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([C002,Vector(323.000, 0.000, 0.000, 323.000),2RFG], [C002,Vector(33.000, 0.000, 0.000, 33.000),2RFG])
```

What I want is:

```
Array([C002,323.000, 0.000, 0.000, 323.000.2RFG], [C002,33.000, 0.000, 0.000, 33.000,2RFG])
```

I know I below code works, but it is not what I want

```
myfile.filter(!_.contains("BatchNumber")).map(line=>line.split("\t")).map(line=>Row(line(0), line(30),line(31),line(32),line(33),line(1))).take(2)
```

because in the real world, I have about 50 columns, I don't want to list them all in the code

```
myfile.filter(!_.contains("BatchNumber")).map(line=>line.split("\t")).map(line=>Row(line(0),(for (i <- 30 to 50) yield line(i)),line(1))).take(2)
```

I try flatMap in below code:

```
scala> myfile.filter(!_.contains("BatchNumber")).map(line=>line.split("\t")).flatMap(line=>Row(line(0),(for (i <- 30 to 33) yield line(i)),line(1))).take(2)
```

but got error

Comment: You can do something like this with Shapeless, but it'll be messy. In my view you're almost definitely best off writing out the values, even if you have dozens of them.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want a tuple with 50 elements rather than a collection of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a work around already:

```
myfile.map(line=>line.split("\t")).map(line=>Row((for (i<-0 to 33 if (i==0) ||  ((i>=30) && (i<=33)) || (i==1)) yield{if (i==30) line(i).toDouble else line(i)}):_*))
```

Turns out I need to yield all result  like this format first: Vector(C002,323.000,0.000,0.000,323.000,2RFG), then do something like this: Row(Vector(C002,323.000,0.000,0.000,323.000,2RFG):_*)